# Export text file and added names in the text field

Tags: java

My code is when user type in the Name text filed, it will export as text file and record the Name. 
For example,

- I typed 1st time "**James**" in the Name text filed, it will appear
  "**James**" in the text file. I type second time "**Agnes**" , it appears
  "**Agnes**" in the text file. But It only appear one name in the text
  file.

  I want all the names appear whatever user type in the text filed.
  How do i modify my codes?

  ```
  try
  {          
      new JTextField();
      // create new file
      String path="C:\\export.txt";
      File file = new File(path);

      // if file doesnt exists, then create it
      if (!file.exists()) 
      {
          file.createNewFile();
      }

      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
      // write in file
      //  bw.write(txtName.getText());
      if (txtName.getText() ==null)
      {
          bw.write(txtName.getText());
          bw.write('\n');
          System.out.print("1st Name:" +txtName.getText());
      }
      else
          if (txtName.getText()!=null)
          {
              //  bw.write('\n');
              bw.write(txtName.getText());
              System.out.print("2nd Name:" +txtName.getText());
          }                      
          // close connection
      bw.flush();
      bw.close();
      fw.close();
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      System.out.println(e);
  }
  ```

Please advise.Thanks

Comment: In your case, using `.write` all the time, when you insert a new text, the old one is deleted. You should append the new text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use append mode when write file, like:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
```

Comment: thz sir, but it only appear in one line
I want to appear next one one after another name...=(

Comment: Hi @coder, if you are in windows system, the newline number should be: `\r\n`, `bw.write("\r\n");`

Comment: but the best way to do it like: "bw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") )"

Comment: thanks sir,
bw.write(System.getProperty("line.separator") ); is working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Edit again:

```
            FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);

            if (txtName.getText()!=null){

            //this line edited 
               bw.write(txtName.getText()+"\n");               
              System.out.print("2nd Name:" +txtName.getText());
           }
```

Comment: thanks sir
the output still only appear in one line 
i want to be in separated one name by one name.
how can i modify?